# How do you initiate an All-Out Attack?

Tags: persona-q

At least in Persona 3 and 4, you had the option to do an All-Out Attack when all of the enemies are knocked down. This does not seem to be the case in Persona Q. But I can't tell what is.

It is also possible the enemy state is just unclear and it does still have the same condition though.

So, what are the necessary conditions to start get an All-Out Attack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to boost at least 3 party members. This doesn't guarantee one though, it's just that 3 is the bare minimum. The more members that are in boost state by the end of the turn, the higher chance there is of an all-out attack!

Comment: Is this completely seperate from knocked down enemies? I know I have gotten one when all enemies were down but I imagine that my team was also all or mostly boosted.

Comment: @Reafexus yes, it seems that it is completely separated from knocked down enemies, for PQ the chance of all-out attacks occurring seems to completely dependent on how many boosted party members you have. 4 or 5 boosted party members almost always trigger all-out attacks, though on some rare chances it doesn't trigger even though you have all of them boosted.